# Local Server Redirected to Internet

Tags: iis, raspberry-pi

1. I have a local Raspberry Pi server running Apache on 192.168.0.112
2. I have an internet server with my own domain running on the same network as the pi with IIS.
3. How do I get one of my sub-domains raspi.mywebsite.com (for example) to redirect **internet** users to the **local** server running on the Pi? Is this possible?

I realize that if users are simply redirected, they will be redirected somewhere on their own network, so that is why I ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is quite simple. I just used the URL Rewrite tool and created an inbound rule. Now my site will take internet users to a page hosted on my Pi LAN server.